# Cannot run compiled java classes in command line

Tags: java

I'm using windows 11 and vscode but have tried using windows terminal too. I have 2 java classes Percolation.java and PercolationStats.java, both run fine in vscode and Percolation compiles but I run any from command line.

Managed to generate class files with `javac -classpath "C:\algs4\algs4.jar" Percolation.java  PercolationStats.java` but cannot run them:

```
PS C:\Users\Lance\Desktop\algorithms\percolations> javac -classpath "C:\algs4\algs4.jar" Percolation.java  PercolationStats.java  
PS C:\Users\Lance\Desktop\algorithms\percolations> java -classpath "C:\algs4\algs4.jar" Percolation        
Error: Could not find or load main class Percolation
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Percolation
PS C:\Users\Lance\Desktop\algorithms\percolations> java -classpath "C:\algs4\algs4.jar" PercolationStats
Error: Could not find or load main class PercolationStats
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PercolationStats
```

I have run other classes the same way.

files are all in same directory and if I add `import Percolation;` it says "The import Percolation cannot be resolved."

Percolation.java

```
package percolations;

import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.WeightedQuickUnionUF;

public class Percolation {
    ...


    public Percolation(int N) {
        ...
    }

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

PercolationStats.java

```
package percolations;

import java.lang.Math;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdRandom;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdStats;

public class PercolationStats {
    private Percolation perc;
    ...

    public PercolationStats(int n, int trials) {
        perc = new Percolation(n);
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PercolationStats stats = new PercolationStats(n, t);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You should include the directory that contains Percolation.class in the class path. Or, just compile these two files together in the same command.

Comment: I thought that's what the * does but compiling together worked but now it cannot find the class when I try run it

java -classpath "C:\algs4\algs4.jar" Percolation      

Error: Could not find or load main class Percolation
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Percolation

Comment: Please post the complete output of the commands together with the prompts & commands you executed (i.e. simply [copy/paste the sequence from your terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/295370/how-to-copy-text-in-the-windows-command-line-cmd)). Right now it's hard to tell what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @Sweeper it is  the directory containing the `percolations` directory that must be in the CLASSPATH (`package percolations;`)

Comment: @user85421 Oops. I totally missed that line.

Comment: You have a package, so if you're running you need to include the classpath to the folder above the package. Ie "build/percolations/PercolationStats.class" you would need "build" on your class path. One way to achieve the correct directory structure is to use `javac -d build path/to/Source.java` That way the generated class files will be placed in the correct folder within build. To run it you just have to include build in your classpath.

Comment: not sure what you guys mean, all files are in same folder except "C:\algs4\algs4.jar"